# Free shipping for the 100 first customers in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to find a way in Woocommerce to allow free shipping for the first 100 customers as a promotional event.

Once the limit of 100 first customers is reached, then standard shipping will be applied.

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple the way to do it with the 2 hooked functions below that will:

1. Auto Add a coupon code to cart with "Free shipping" option enabled to 1st 100 customers.
2. To hide other shipping methods when "Free shipping" is available.

**But you will have:**

1. In WooCommerce > Settings > shipping, for each shipping zone set a "Free shipping" Method and chose one of this options:

   - A valid free shipping coupon
   - A minimum order amount OR a coupon
2. To set a special coupon code before in WooCommerce > Coupons with the following settings:

   - General > Discount type: Fixed cart
   - General > Amount: 0
   - General > Allow free shipping: enabled
   - Usage limit > Usage limit per coupon: 100
   - Usage limit > Usage limit per user: 1

Here is the code:

```php
// Auto apply "free_shipping" coupon for first hundred
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_apply_free_shipping_coupon_first_hundred', 20, 1 );
function auto_apply_free_shipping_coupon_first_hundred( $cart ) {

    // HERE define  your free shipping coupon code
    $coupon_code = 'summer';// 'freeship100';

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Coupon object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

    // After 100 usages exit
    if( $coupon->get_usage_count() > 100 ) return;

    // Auto-apply "free shipping" coupon code
    if ( ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) && is_cart() ){
        $cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __('You have win Free shipping for the first 100 customers'), 'notice');
    }
}

// Hide Others Shipping methods when "Free shipping is available
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_others_when_free_shipping_is_available', 100 );
function hide_others_when_free_shipping_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce version 3+